# How does the cpu able itself to detect the transitors 0 or 1?

Tags: transistors

I am a newbie to the field of electronics and would like to know how does the cpu detect the transistor is either on or off.!
of how much i read there is a comparator.!
so what device reads the transistor and detects?

Comment: You are sort of asking how a brain detects whether a neuron is firing or not. The brain doesn't, the brain is at a different abstraction level than a neuron. Hence your first question makes no sense. I can't even parse your second sentence.

Comment: [how to build a 4-bit computer using discrete transistors](http://www.waitingforfriday.com/index.php/4-Bit_Computer)

Comment: Why so many down votes on this? The grammar is poor, but that can be fixed. The question indicates some serious misconceptions, but isn't that part of what we are here to clear up?

Answer (score 1):

When a transistor is "on", it can conduct more current than when "off".  This change in current can be sensed by other circuitry which contains even more transistors, which eventually change something the outside world can see, like a voltage on a output pin.

Comment: i am surprised by the responses.!
Well it mite not make sense i mentioned that am totally new.!
so if you have a  HArd drive!
the transistors in a cpu will read the data in it ,!
detecting the levels.!
could i get a detailed understanding of how this happens!
mite be through some pdf..!

Answer (score 0):

Transistors are not only used for data storage inside a modern electronic CPU, but for everything else. Events happen in the CPU because transistors drive other transistors.

A transistor can react whether another transistor is on and off because a voltage can be conveyed from one transistor circuit (understood as the output of that circuit) to another, where it serves as input, similarly to how analog signals are conveyed between stages in an amplifier.

Transistor circuits can be constructed which take multiple inputs and implement logic functions like "and" and "or".

Transistor circuits can also use their own output as their input. This feedback arrangement can cause curious things to happen, such as circuits which exhibit state, in other words, memory.

Circuits that hold stable states due to short, local feedback loops can be involved in more complex, larger feedback loops, whose effects are carefully controlled by latching and clocking, which change the state in complicated ways to make computation happen.

Comment: yeah well thanks for the kind response!:)!
so all i wanted to know in depth is in a cpu!
how are the transistors able to detect another transistor is either on or off!!
at physical level.?

Regards

Comment: You should study transistors and transistor circuits. Everything will become clear. Transistor circuits can be hooked up together in stages. One transistor stage produces an output, usually a voltage level. This is directly connected as the input of another transistor stage which reacts to the voltage.